# "Хочешь (-) не хочешь"

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Нужен ли дефис в выражении "хочешь (-) не хочешь"? Когда дефис между двумя словами - это понятно, но тут присутствует частица "не", которая пишется с глаголом раздельно. Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совершенно правы, в подобных случаях графический дефис очевидно исключен просто по соображениям наглядности. В некоторых случаях, когда приходится соединять дефисом части из более чем одного слова, дефис заменяется на тире. 
Но в разбираемом обороте словарями (Лоптин) рекомендуется раздельное написание: **"хочешь не хочешь"**.

Answer (score 1):

Слова *хочешь не хочешь* пишутся раздельно. Без частицы НЕ будет дефис.